# Trying to create a connect 4 game with text-base then implement GUI later

Tags: python, list, class, tkinter

```
class Board:    
    def __init__(self, N):
        '''Board for a Connect-N game, the board will have N+2 Col and N+3 Rows'''
        self.num_row = N + 3
        self.num_col = N + 2        
        self.cols = [Column(self.num_row) for i in range(self.num_col)]
        self.row = [Column(self.num_col) for i in range(self.num_row)]
        pass
        #return
    
    def display(self):
        '''display the board'''
        
        
        
        print ('\u26AA' '\u26AB')         
        #for rown in range(3):
        #    for col in range(2):
        #        btn = tk.Button(width = '5',height = '2', text = '')
        #        btn.bind("<Button-1>", on_btn_click)
        #        btn.grid(row = rown, column = col )
    
    def drop_disk(self, c):
        '''drop a disk at column c'''
        pass

    def check_winning_condition(self):
        '''check if there is a winner'''
        return True
    
class Column:
    def __init__(self, r):
        '''each column has r rows'''
        self.rows = [0]*r
    
N = 4 #standard Connect-4
board = Board(N)
board.display()
```

I am trying to create a **connect-4 game** but not sure how to do it. I got some outline but don't know how to create it. I'm trying to create a board with 2 columns and 3 rows.
The image is what I want it to look like but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  "It didn't work" is not a problem specification.

Comment: The question you *actually* asked, "I'm not sure how to do it", is out of scope for Stack Overflow.  You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `__str__` method to print your board:
Once the game works the way you need, you can easily build a GUI with `tkinter` around it, in a separate set of files.

In the following example, I am using a `list of lists` to represent the board. I changed the settings to represent the traditional 6 rows and 7 columns of connect-4.

```
class Board:    
    def __init__(self, N):
        '''Board for a Connect-N game, the board will have N+2 Col and N+3 Rows'''
        self.num_row = N + 2
        self.num_col = N + 3        
        self.cells = [[None for _ in range(self.num_col)] for _ in range(self.num_row)]
    
    def __str__(self):
        res = []
        for row in self.cells:
            for cell in row:
                c = cell
                if cell is None:
                    c = '.'
                res.append(f'{c} ')
            res.append('\n')
        return ''.join(res)

    
    def drop_disk(self, c, player='X'):
        '''drop a disk at column c
        return True if successful
        '''
        for r, row in enumerate(self.cells):
            if row[c] is None:
                continue
            elif r == 0:
                break
            self.cells[r-1][c] = player
            return True
        else:   # this executes when there is `no break`
            self.cells[r][c] = player
            return True
        return False
        

    def check_winning_condition(self):
        '''check if there is a winner'''
        return True

N = 4 #standard Connect-4
board = Board(N)
print(board)
```

**output:**

```
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . .
```

I also added the `drop_disk` method in order to test the output; the method returns `True` if a disc was successfully played, and `False` otherwise.

```
print(board.drop_disk(3, 'X'))
print(board)
print(board.drop_disk(3, 'O'))
print(board)
print(board.drop_disk(4, 'X'))
print(board)
print(board.drop_disk(5, 'O'))
print(board)
print(board.drop_disk(3, 'X'))
print(board)
print(board.drop_disk(3, 'O'))
print(board)
print(board.drop_disk(3, 'X'))
print(board)
print(board.drop_disk(3, 'O'))
print(board)
print(board.drop_disk(3, 'X'))
print(board)
print(board.drop_disk(3, 'O'))
print(board)
```

**Output:**

```
True
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . X . . . 

True
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . O . . . 
. . . X . . . 

True
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . O . . . 
. . . X X . . 

True
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . O . . . 
. . . X X O . 

True
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . X . . . 
. . . O . . . 
. . . X X O . 

True
. . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . . O . . . 
. . . X . . . 
. . . O . . . 
. . . X X O . 

True
. . . . . . . 
. . . X . . . 
. . . O . . . 
. . . X . . . 
. . . O . . . 
. . . X X O . 

True
. . . O . . . 
. . . X . . . 
. . . O . . . 
. . . X . . . 
. . . O . . . 
. . . X X O . 

False
. . . O . . . 
. . . X . . . 
. . . O . . . 
. . . X . . . 
. . . O . . . 
. . . X X O . 

False
. . . O . . . 
. . . X . . . 
. . . O . . . 
. . . X . . . 
. . . O . . . 
. . . X X O .
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. Is it alright for me to use and change the code to my liking?  and what should be the first step for a beginner

Comment: I not sure how to put the code in Tkinter. when bind the button it doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: You are very welcome @Sizzy. My suggestion is to first build a working game in the console (`print` statements, and `input`); once you have a game working, you can try to build a gui. It is easier if your code is modular and clearly separates the input/output from the logic of the game. You can ask new questions when you get stuck, I, or someone from the stack community will be happy to help you.

Comment: Wonderful, congratulations.

Comment: Thank you, I did create the GUI but it does not work the way that I wanted. I tried to combine the text-base and Tkinter together but it just have a problem. So I create a new GUI.(below the connect 4 games). Thank you